# Is there a way to define the task class outside the build.gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, task

This is just a dummy task class I implemented from https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_outcomes

**root - build.gradle**

```
class Hello extends DefaultTask {
    @Input
    String dummy = "hello"

    @TaskAction
    void hello() {
        System.out.println(dummy);
    }
}

task Hellotask(type: Hello) {
    dummy= 'dummy'
}
```

---

Is there any way I could move this class outside `build.gradle` and just add the task type `Hello` to my custom task?

For instance, move the `Hello.java` to `Module1` and access it from a custom task in the root `build.gradle`

```
root
 -Module1
    -Hello.java      ----- the task class Hello
    -build.gradle
 -Module2
    -build.gradle
 -build.gradle
```

**root - build.gradle**

```
task Hellotask(type: Hello) {
    dummy= 'dummy'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can put the class in the `buildSrc` folder. Gradle will automatically build this and make it available in your build.

```
root
 -Module1
    -buildSrc/src/main/java/Hello.java      ----- the task class Hello
    -build.gradle
 -Module2
    -build.gradle
 -build.gradle
```

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:packaging_a_task_class)  for more information.

Comment: I've been asked to work on a composite build where buildSrc is not preferred, as the modules are highly functional and specific .Is there any other way other than including the class in buildSrc?

Comment: You could put the tasks in an own project and publish artifacts from there. But I would recommend such an approach only if the tasks should be reusable.

I don't know about another approach, sorry.